# Doctrine Changing Transaction Isolation Level

Tags: mysql, doctrine, transaction-isolation

I'd like to change the transaction isolation level of all queries/updates to the mysql database to Read Committed.  As we are using a google application database we cannot change it in the mysql configuration and thus need to change it in the connection to the database.

We are using Doctrine and Symfony3 and I'm struggling to see how this can be achieved apart from issuing a command such as

```
 $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->prepare('SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED')->execute();
```

I'm pretty sure there is some support for changing the Transaction Isolation but I can't seem to work out how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.10/reference/transactions.html documents:

> The Doctrine\DBAL\Connection also has methods to control the transaction isolation level as supported by the underlying database. Connection#setTransactionIsolation($level) and Connection#getTransactionIsolation() can be used for that purpose. The possible isolation levels are represented by the following constants:

See the documentation for the list of constants for isolation levels.

So you can run this on every connection:

```
$this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->setTransactionIsolation($level);
```

If you want it to be the default, so you don't have to set it in every connection, you'll have to set that in the MySQL server's `my.cnf` file. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_transaction_isolation

If you can't change the `my.cnf` globally, then you'll have to set it yourself for every connection using a line of code as shown above.

Comment: Thank you Bill - in Symfony the doctrine.yaml file is used to configure the connection, perhaps I misunderstand but this isn't clear how I can configure the app to always set the transaction isolation at connection